# Leaflet: Pause and resume marker animation using SnakeIn

Tags: javascript, animation, leaflet, marker

[IvanSanchez's Snakein Animation for Leaflet](https://github.com/IvanSanchez/Leaflet.Polyline.SnakeAnim/blob/master/demo-group.gif) is very useful for marker animation. 
I am wondering if anyone knows how to make it pauses while animating, and then resumes from the paused point /or start animating over.

For example, the second marker was just drawn, if I click pause, it will stay there until I click "resume". When I click "resume", the next marker will be drawn and so on. If I click restart, it will start over from beginning.

An example will be helpful.

Thank you

Comment: Try https://github.com/hallahan/LeafletPlayback

Comment: Thanks, It s a nice plugin. I am trying to use Snake-In of @IvanSanchez at the moment. :/

Comment: @xmojmr Is the LeafletPlayback has npm support?

Comment: probably not, see https://github.com/hallahan/LeafletPlayback/issues/35